# Is polynomial ring of infinite many variables Laskerian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, we say $R$ is a Lasker ring, if every ideal of $R$ has [primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition). By Hilbert basis theorem and Lasker-Noether theorem (every Noether ring is a Lasker ring), polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,\dots,z_d]$ is Laskerian, if $d<\infty$. Let $\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,\dots]$ denote the polynomial ring of countable many invariables. It is easy to see $\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,\dots]$ is not Noetherian, for example, consider $${\cal I}=\{p \in \mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,\dots]: p(0)=0\},$$ then $\cal I$ is not finitely generated.

> Question:  Is $\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,\dots]$ a Lasker ring?

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly counter example"? An example of ideal which can't have a primary decomposition?

Comment: @user26857 Yes.

Comment: How to build such an example is suggested in the proof of Theorem 4 from the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper *[The Laskerian Property, Power Series Rings and Noetherian Spectra](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243060603_The_Laskerian_Property_Power_Series_Rings_and_Noetherian_Spectra)*, Gilmer and Heinzer show that a Laskerian ring has Noetherian spectrum. But a polynomial ring in countable many indeterminates over a field has no Noetherian spectrum, so it can't be Laskerian.